# Symmetric MAC benefit

Tags: mac

I have a question about symmetric message authentication codes (MACs).

Say Bob sends encrypted messages to Alice using a symmetric cipher. As I understand it:

(1) Their threat model could or should include the risk of an active attacker sending Alice maliciously crafted ciphertexts for the purpose of exploiting bugs in her decryption program;

(2) Bob and Alice can eliminate that risk by ensuring that Bob MACs his ciphertexts, and Alice checks those MACs before decrypting. (This of course assumes that Bob himself will not send Alice maliciously crafted ciphertexts.)

Is all that correct?

If so, here is my question. In principle, Alice’s program is just as likely to have exploitable bugs in its MAC verification code, as in its decryption code. So aren’t you just swapping the risk of maliciously crafted ciphertexts, for that of maliciously crafted MACs?

That is, can you say that MACing ciphertexts eliminates the decrypting party’s exposure to maliciously crafted ciphertexts, without also adding that it exposes them to the new risk (previously not relevant) of maliciously crafted MACs?

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) correctly describe a threat model. (2) is correct.

> Alice’s program is just as likely to have exploitable bugs in its MAC verification code, as in its decryption code. So aren’t you just swapping the risk of maliciously crafted ciphertexts, for that of maliciously crafted MACs?

That objection does not work well, because the bugs in Alice's decryption program that the MAC is trying to mitigate are of a nature that makes them unlikely to occur for a MAC. Broadly, they are information leak (side channels) about the result of the decryption. Like, if a padding check at the end of the decrypted plaintext passes; or if the beginning of the deciphered plaintext starts with some expected header. When a real-life program uses unauthenticated encryption supplied as a black box, it's next to impossible to avoid such side channels from outside the decryption black box. They may lead or not to an exploitable attack, but it's difficult to ascertain they do not.

By contrast, there is no such check with a MAC. The MAC is recomputed and compared to that supplied. When it comes to the most common side-channel (timing), one of few goofs likely to creep is that it's possible to determine (e.g. by timing) how many bytes or words of the MAC match, but there are known mitigations for that:

- Constant-time comparison, which is easy and solves the issue 100%.
- Using the MAC as part of a challenge/response protocol where inherently there is a single chance to get the MAC correct, also solving that issue 100%.
- Counting incorrect MACs and raising alarm after a few.
- For an 8-byte MAC and an ideally exploitable timing variation, an attacker needs an expected $\approx2^{10}$ attempts to find the MAC; that will slow them down.
- We are talking about a very small timing variation, often not exploitable, rather than a typically much larger one. Combined with the above that makes exploitation possible only in some rare scenarios (I did met that with a poorly implemented Smard Card in the 1990s).

As an aside: when it comes to other side channels like recovery of key by power analysis, yes it's comparably likely that the MAC key and the encryption key are recovered, especially if both are based on the same crypto primitive. But at least that's two keys to recover.

---

update following comment:

> I was thinking of bugs like, eg., exploitable buffer overflows.

There can be a buffer overflow in the reception path, but that's an issue not involving crypto and that must be mitigated independently. MAC verification by itself is unlikely to cause buffer overflow, at least of the out-of-bound write kind. A check of MAC of ciphertext efficiently prevents the kind of buffer overflow caused by decryption into too small a buffer.

Other buffer overflows tend not to be in the encryption or MAC parts themselves. They lie in the software using the deciphered plaintext. That's one of many reasons why most applications that need encryption also need to ensure that the deciphered plaintext matches what was encrypted, including it's length. A MAC is a mean for this. The first section of this answer focuses on why it is often recommended to MAC the ciphertext rather than the plaintext.

> So on balance it’s best to protect the ciphertext by using a MAC, even if that exchanges the risk of bugs from malformed ciphertexts, for a similar risk of bugs from malformed MACs.

I'd say it's better to MAC the ciphertext rather than the plaintext *if* we additionally make sure that the encryption keys and the MAC keys are strongly tied together, e.g. derived from a common one, as is common practice; and can somewhat be confident there is no error in the decryption (fault injection is not a threat, or mitigated).

But the debate on MAC-then-encrypt (MAC the plaintext) or encrypt-then-MAC (MAC the ciphertext) is obsolete in most contexts: [authenticated encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption) like AES-GCM now is widely available, and (if secure) does the job in an integrated way, and at lower computational cost.

Comment: Tks for answer. I was thinking of bugs like, eg., exploitable buffer overflows. Would you agree that those kinds of bugs are just as likely for the MAC, as for the ciphertext? If so, could I think of it like:  “Certain bugs, eg. buffer overflows, are just as likely for MACs as for ciphertexts. However, certain practical attacks, eg. timing attacks, work on ciphertexts only (not on MACs). So on balance it’s best to protect the ciphertext by using a MAC, even if that exchanges the risk of bugs from malformed ciphertexts, for a similar risk of bugs from malformed MACs.”  ??  TIA

Comment: Thanks for comprehensive answer.